# how to run cron job every 3 months?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

What would be the crontab entry look like for a job that runs on the first day of every third month?

Comment: [https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1_*/3_*](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1_*/3_*)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The following will run script on the 1st of Jan, Apr, Jul and Oct at 03:30

```
30 03 01 Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct * /path/to/script
```

Alternatively, but less obvious

```
30 03 01 */3 * /path/to/script
```

Will run every three months at 03:30 on the 1st of Jan,Apr,Jul and Oct.

Comment: +1: I always thought the / notation was the MOST obvious...I use it wherever possible. (Words in the scheduling part of the crontab freak me out...I'd do: "0 0 1 3,6,9,12 * /path/to/script.bash" if I couldn't do /3)

Comment: wouldn't `*/3` be every four months (12/3 = 4)?

Comment: @warren No it would not. The logic here is more of a mod truth statement. Ex: if(12%3 == 0): run_script(). I thought about this as well! Great question.

Comment: @Goahnary I realized that a while after I asked for the clarification, too :)

Comment: @warren it really should be a mod operator rather than a division. But oh well ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Goahnary So I think it will run on Mar, Jun, Sep, & Dec right rather than in answer: 'Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct'

Answer (score 8):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) has a nice explanation about how to configure Cron.

For your specific case you could run a [Cron Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRON_expression) to run every 3 months- obviously change the months to suit your schedule.

```
0 0 1 JAN,APR,JUL,OCT  * /path/to/script.bash
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is good, thou I'd use an alternative with simpler numbers and easier to read:
[https://crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1_*/3_*)

```
0 0 1 */3 *
```

Read like this: “At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 in every 3rd month.”

Answer (score 0):

For JIRA (and other 6 digit cron expressions):

0 0 0 1 JAN,APR,JUL,OCT ?